# Run GitLab job when all previous jobs passed or otherwise be able to run it manually

Tags: deployment, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline, manual

I have a pipeline consisting of build, test1, test2, deploy.

I want the deploy to be run always when test1 and test2 stages are successful but, in case some of them fails (can be both) I want to be able to run manually the deploy stage anyway.

I know how to configure both scenarios separately, so I'm asking how to have both behaviors combined if possible.

Thanks.